# Differential on Lie group $SO(3)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, closed-form

Consider the decomposition of any rotation matrix $R\in SO(3)$ as
$$ R=\exp(\theta_3 \hat{e}_3)\exp(\theta_1\hat e_1 + \theta_2 \hat e_2)$$
where the hat designates the [hat operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_operator),
and the application $\phi$ that "extracts" the angles $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$:
\begin{align}
\phi: SO(3)&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \\
 R &\longmapsto (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)
\end{align}

Is it possible to derive a closed-form expression for $d\phi$?

---

What I have done: I computed $d(\phi^{-1})$: 
$$\phi^{-1}=\mathrm{comp}\circ \alpha$$
where $\mathrm{comp}$ is the product in $SO(3)$ and 
$$\alpha:(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)\longmapsto (\exp(\theta_3 \hat e_3),\exp(\theta_1\hat e_1 + \theta_2 \hat e_2))$$

I find, with $\Theta = (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$:
\begin{align}d(\phi^{-1})(\Theta)(u)& = d(\mathrm{comp}(\alpha(\Theta))(d\alpha(\Theta)(u)) \\
& = \mathrm{Ad}\big(\mathrm{inv}\circ\exp(\theta_1\hat e_1 + \theta_2 \hat e_2)\big)(d\exp(\theta_3\hat e_3)(u)) + d\exp(\theta_1\hat e_1 + \theta_2 \hat e_2)(u)
\end{align}

and then I thought of using the identity:
$$d\phi(R)= \big( d(\phi^{-1})(\phi(R))\big)^{-1}$$

This provides a way of computing $d\phi(R)$ numerically. Any better idea?